# SQL with conditional where

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone please assist with the below query ?

I have a table like below :

```
Code        alias   user
--------    -----   -------
7305553     BPP     (null)
8136852     BPP     AYU
8136852     BPP     TKL
7305553     BPFX    (null)
8136848     BPFX    YAO
11903927    CIX     (null)
```

And I want to retrieve the "Code" value by passing "alias" and "user" values, however when the "user" doesn't match/exist, I'd need the row with the null user. 
Eg :

```
select Code from my_table where alias = 'BPP' and user = 'TEST'
```

should return the 1st line code value (7305553) , as user "TEST" doesn't exist. Is this kind of best-matching behavior possible with some kind of conditional "where" ? (with some kind of case statement?)

Comment: ```select Code from my_table where alias = 'BPP' and (user = 'TEST' OR user IS NULL) ORDER by user ASC;```
Then you get one or two rows. Just adjust the ORDER clause to get the NULL as a second record when you have two ones, so you are sure which one is the NULL.

Comment: @AntonMitsev limit it to one also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CODE
FROM
    MY_TABLE
WHERE
    ALIAS = 'BPP'
    AND (USER = 'TEST' OR USER IS NULL)
    ORDER BY USER NULLS LAST
    FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks very much. Best answer I think

Answer (score 0):

Try CASE in MySQL :

```
SELECT
    CODE
FROM
    MY_TABLE
WHERE
    ALIAS = 'BPP'
AND 
    CASE 
        WHEN USER != 'TEST' THEN 1=1 
        ELSE USER = 'TEST'
    END;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however as per the tag I'm on oracle and not mysql

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't : `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Comment: I already tried it with "END" as well on my side, still same error

Comment: Hope, There will be another syntax. I haven't Oracle DB so that i can't check for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the row if the alias equals 'BPP' and the user equals 'TEST'
**OR**
The alias equals 'BPP' and the user `IS NULL` and there is no alias 'BPP' and user 'TEST'

```
select code from my_table where 
(alias = 'BPP' and user = 'TEST')
or
(alias = 'BPP' and user IS NULL and NOT EXIST (select 'X' from my_table where alias = 'BPP' and user = 'TEST'))
```